# error after making smclib

Tags: ros, roscore, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I cannot run roscore after I download and make smclib (fuerte version).

This is output error of typing "roswtf":

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 3 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH [/root/catkin_ws/src:/root/ros_core_ws/install/share:/root/ros_core_ws/install/stacks] point to an existing directory: 
 * /root/ros_core_ws/install/stacks

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/root/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages] point to a directory: 
 * /root/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

ERROR ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR is invalid: ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR [/root/catkin_ws/build/test_results] is not writable ================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://192.168.1.1:11311]
```

This is the output error of typing "roscore":

```
WARNING(s) in /root/catkin_ws/src/bondcore/smclib/build/smc_6_0_1/lib/Php/package.xml:
- The "package" tag must not have the following attributes: packagerversion, xmlns, xmlns:tasks, version, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation
- The manifest must not contain the following tags: lead, changelog, notes, uri, summary, stability, dependencies, time, date, phprelease, contents
- The "version" tag must not contain the following children: release, api
- The "license" tag must not have the following attributes: uri Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 263, in main
    p.start()
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self.runner.launch()
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 644, in launch
    self._setup()
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 621, in _setup
    self._launch_core_nodes()
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 496, in _launch_core_nodes
    name, success = self.launch_node(node, core=True)
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 524, in launch_node
    process = create_node_process(self.run_id, node, master.uri)
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/nodeprocess.py", line 131, in create_node_process
    args = create_local_process_args(node, machine)
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/node_args.py", line 234, in create_local_process_args
    matches = roslib.packages.find_node(node.package, node.type, rospack)
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 400, in find_node
    return find_resource(pkg, node_type, filter_fn=_executable_filter, rospack=rospack)
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 497, in find_resource
    search_paths = catkin_find(search_dirs=['libexec', 'share'], project=pkg, first_matching_workspace_only=True)
  File "/root/ros_core_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py", line 99, in find_in_workspaces
    packages = find_packages(source_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 81, in find_packages
    package = parse_package(os.path.join(basepath, path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 257, in parse_package
    return parse_package_string(f.read(), filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 387, in parse_package_string
    pkg.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 158, in validate
    raise InvalidPackage('\n'.join(errors))
InvalidPackage: Invalid package manifest "/root/catkin_ws/src/bondcore/smclib/build/smc_6_0_1/lib/Php/package.xml": Package version must not be empty Package must declare at least one maintainer [master] killing on exit
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57014/error-after-making-smclib/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With all those errors it looks like you downloaded the wrong version of smclib.

By the way it is also not recommended to build and run as root.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-22**:
Thanks for your reply. After I change the version to groovy, it works.